# Two columned <li> layout

Tags: html, css

I think i might be missing something basic. Have been on it for few hours now and cannot make it work.

http://jsfiddle.net/x4bLtt7b/

```
<div class="customerInfo">
<form class="form-style">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="field1">field1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field1" maxlength="100"> <span>field1 info</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="field2">field2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field2" maxlength="100"> <span>field2 info</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="field3">field3</label>
            <input type="text" name="field3" maxlength="100"> <span>field3 info</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="field4">field4</label>
            <input type="text" name="field4" maxlength="100"> <span>field4 info</span>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="field5">field5</label>
            <input type="text" name="field5" maxlength="100"> <span>field5 info</span>

        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I just need the layout to be two columned, i.e. The field1/field2 pair should be on the same row (adjacent to each other). Same for field3/field4 pair and so on.

It seemed pretty simple to start with but i just couldn't get it to work yet. Any feedback is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: what part of your CSS should make them render in two columns? There is no float or inline-block

Comment: What browser support are you aiming for?

Comment: @Luizgrs - i tried using float and inline and inline-blocks on the lis but that didnt help. Just put the code working this far on jsfiddle

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Chrome/firefox mainly. Not IE if you are asking that :)

Comment: @pinaki Good news is that all modern versions of today's browser support Flexbox (including IE10+). It would be perfect for this type of layout.

Comment: I think you're better to post a screen shot with the desire look of it.

Comment: @sdcr - I got the answer already this time but will remember the tip the next time. Check Manoj's answer works perfectly.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - What is the difference between using flex and inline-block? Should i be conerned about using one over another?

Comment: @pinaki Flexbox is far more powerful, but has far less browser-support (only supported in modern browsers, IE10+). The alternate, `inline-block`, will have far better browser support, but offer less control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regular CSS method:**

Use this method if you need full browser support or else switch to flexbox. 
Set a width for the list and display to inline-block

```
.form-style li {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 40%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/x4bLtt7b/1/)

**Flexbox Method:**

This is better but supported only by modern browsers.

```
.form-style ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/x4bLtt7b/9/)

**Output**

[image: Output 2 column li]

Comment: Perfect. This is what i was looking for. I swear I thought I already tried that :). Thanks

Comment: Haha! Welcome pinaki! :)

Comment: I don't think it always stays with 2 cols when the window is much narrower.

Comment: It depends on Pinaki's preference. He can use media queries and lower the width for extra small devices.

Comment: @sdcr - yes i noticed that too. But this will work for me. It is only for PC and if the screen size is reduced, the client doesn't mind one field per row :)

Comment: Be aware of the inline block white space thing https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ - if you need it to be pixel perfect.

Comment: Updated the code with `flexbox` method. It seems better and spacing is taken care of without setting custom margin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this:

```
.form-style li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Adjust the width setting want you want.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/x4bLtt7b/3/